# Import users from an external server with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-import

I'm doing my first steps with Sharepoint and I'm not clear how to import users from an external server using AD. The point is that I set as "Fully Qualified Domain Name", the server name (it could be an IP). I think this is the error. Can someone give me a clue?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This technet article would be a good start. I'll add code snippets in a little while.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meacoex/archive/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx